# Convert a dataframe to large character

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe but need to convert it to a large character. Here is an example of the dataframe structure:

```
texts <- c("TEXT 1", "TEXT 2", "TEXT 3")
data <- data.frame(texts)
```

I need this structure:

```
[1] "TEXT 1" "TEXT 2" "TEXT 3"
```

[image: I need the data to stay in this structure]

I already tried using function `as.character()` , but it does not work as it converts all the lines to a single line.

Comment: Please show an example of you dataframe and your desired output (in code - not pictures). I have a suspicion you are looking for `as.list(texts)` or such

Comment: @DavidArenburg insert the example of the structure. I got it transforming into array and then into character:
as.character(as.matrix())

Comment: Please also show the desired output should look like

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thank you by tips

Comment: You only have one column?  Does `unlist(data, use.names = FALSE)` works for you?

Comment: @DavidArenburg only one collumn. Don't work because transform to a factor

Comment: @Sotos work. Thank you

Comment: So don't make it a factor in the first place. When creating the dataframe set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` or put `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` at the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transpose and concatenate, i.e.

```
c(t(data))
#[1] "TEXT 1" "TEXT 2" "TEXT 3"
```